# Cron не создаёт файл в каталоге

Tags: php, cron, crontab

Выполняется файл php, в нем есть некий код и в конце он должен создать файл, но не создаёт, крон срабатывает и код выполняется но файл создать не получается.
Если ссылку открыть через браузер то файл отрабатывает корректно.

Крон редактирую командой `sudo crontab -e -u www-data`

Comment: Каталог в котором файл создаётся внутри php скрипта прописан относительно или абсолютно?

Comment: Относительный путь, но через браузер страницу если открыть он же корректно создаёт файл

Comment: Спасибо ! Путь надо было указать абсолютный от корня сайта